# Navigation bar layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I am having problems getting my navigation bar to look like the photo below using bootstrap.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When the screen resolution became smaller the images would go on top and bottom of the actual navigation links instead of shrinking as one whole piece. Is there a better layout to accomplish this?

Comment: can you please include a demo in your question?

Comment: So you're complaining about your page being responsive. Nice one.